# How to enable middle mouse button click paste in VS Code on Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

In text fields and other text editors in Ubuntu, pressing the middle mouse button will copy whatever text is currently highlighted into the current pointer position. This is not working in Visual Studio Code v1.0.0. How do I enable it?

Comment: Did you check out https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/110 ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've found an [issue](http://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/110) on VsCode's git repo, which will resolve the aforementioned problem. They do mention they may be a performance impact (I've not used it in earnest).

> With the March release, it will be under a setting called `"editor.selectionClipboard"`, which is off by default until we better understand the perf implications of writing to the clipboard on every selection change.

Comment: This setting has a pretty dark description for what it resolves. In my case I wanted just the opposite to avoid errors in my code. Take a look here for details https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/14610 .

Comment: it seems like this setting no longer exists. I am using; code-server: v4.14.1 , 
Code: 1.79.2